# Weird derivatives implication

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

If you assume that

$$ \frac{d}{dx}[x(1-x)X(x)] = (b-cx)X(x) $$

and work out that

$$ (b-cx)X = \frac{x(1-x)}{x(1-x)}(b-cx)X = x(1-x)X(\frac{b}{x}-\frac{c-b}{1-x})$$

how does

$$\frac{d}{dx}[x(1-x)X] =  x(1-x)X(\frac{b}{x}-\frac{c-b}{1-x})$$

imply that

$$x(1-x)X=Ax^b(1-x)^{c-b}$$

for some constant $A$? I can't see it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Y(x)=x(1-x)X(x)$. Then you get a separable equation for $Y(x)$, which you can solve in the usual way.